# Get all objects again after passing a filtered list to template in django

Tags: python, django, django-templates, django-views

I am building a django web application. one area has many points, the relationship is saved within the point (the point model has a foreign key to its area).

the web app has a page for each area and shows the list of points. the area is determined by the url. my view parses the kwargs from the url.py and filters the list of all area objects:

```
class PointView(ListView):
    model = Point
    template_name = 'point_list_template.html'
    def get_queryset(self):
        area_title = self.kwargs['area_title']
        return Point.objects.filter(area__title = area_title)
```

that works quite fine, the page lists all points belonging to the required area. now i want to list all other areas at the bottom of the page except the area i am displaying right now. obviously

```
{% for area in Area.objects.all %}
```

gives me only the one area i am displaying right now (the one determined by the url). how can i access all area objects in the template or pass the list from the view?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll need to add them to the context yourself. Overriding `get_context_data` is the best place for that:

```
def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    context = super(PointView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
    context['all_areas'] = Area.objects.exclude(title=self.kwargs['area_title'])
    return context
```

and now access that in the template with `all_areas`.